# Marketing Cloud & Formstack Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, list

Integrating a form from Formstack to find out that the integration can only populate a LIST within SFMC.

Is there any way to personalize this list so that I can have the fields on the FormStack from populate entirely?

This is how it looks in FormStack (you can see it's based on lists and give you limited fields to create a record with):
[image]

I'd like to be able to have a list that actually incorporates the First/Last Name of the contact.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormStack integration to Marketing Cloud is quite limited as you have observed.

I'd recommend that you consider using FormAssembly which offers similar functionality to FormStack and has a much stronger [integration with Marketing Cloud](https://help.formassembly.com/help/484405-salesforce-marketing-cloud-exacttarget-connector), through its ability to add records to Lists or Data Extensions.